# JDBC remote acces to mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

I've been using a local database for my java projet using wamp and MYSQL, everything worked fine.
Recently i set up an AWS EC2 vm on windows server. Wamp and Mysql are installed on it.

i managed to give remote access to apache and mysql so **i'm able to acces phpmyadmin, the db and interactif with it from an external computer through a brower using its address : http://15.188.65.36/phpmyadmin/**

but when i change what i had before (for my local wamp) which worked fine

```
public static ResultSet execute(String requete) {
        Connection connexion;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        try {
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname","user","*********");
            stmt = connexion.createStatement();
            if(stmt.execute(requete)) {
                res = stmt.getResultSet();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

for

```
public static ResultSet execute(String requete) {
        Connection connexion;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        try {
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://15.188.65.36:3306/dbname","user","*********");
            stmt = connexion.createStatement();
            if(stmt.execute(requete)) {
                res = stmt.getResultSet();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

It's not working anymore, it seems that it can't connect, i receive this error :

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Looks like port 3306 is closed on this server.

Comment: How do you know that ? And how can i fix it ?

Comment: I checked it with nmap. I think this answer might help. https://superuser.com/questions/432794/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-my-wamp-server